# Showing that the fraction field of $\Bbb Z[[t]]$ is strictly contained in the Laurent formal series field $\Bbb Q((t))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Showing that the fraction field of $\Bbb Z[[t]]$ is strictly contained in the Laurent formal series field $\Bbb Q((t))$

A hint is to consider $e^t=1+t+{t^2\over2}+...+{t^n\over n!}+...$

So $e^t\in\Bbb Q((t))$ is obvious. But why isn't it in the fraction field of $\Bbb Z[[t]]$? after all ${t^n\over n!}$ is in Frac$(\Bbb Z[[t]]$) $\forall n\in\Bbb Z$

Comment: Note that "infinite sum" is not a ring operation.

Answer (score 4):

Assume $e^t\in \operatorname{Frac}(\mathbb{Z}[[t]])$, then there exist $f,g\in \mathbb{Z}[[t]]$ coprime such that $e^t = \frac{f}{g}$. Thus, we get $f=e^t g$. For $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we get

$$ f_n = \sum_{j=0}^n \frac{g_{n-j}}{j!}$$

and thus

$$ g_0 = n!f_n - \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{n! g_{n-j}}{j!}.$$

Set $n=p$ for some prime and deduce that $p$ divides $g_0$. Hence, we have $g_0=0$, but then we get

$$ f_0= \frac{g_0}{0!} =0 $$

this contradicts the assumption that $f,g$ were coprime (as now $f$ and $g$ have the common factor $t$).

Comment: @MarcPaul Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: $p$ divides $f_0$ or $g_0$?

Comment: @StanislasHildebrandt I should be $g_0$. I've changed it.

Comment: Beautiful argument!